# properly use session to store a variable android studio

Tags: android

hello im very new to coding in android studio so here is the scenario i have this user that logs in then i get his username i need to store the user's username because i needed to use it on the other pages in my project so what i did was do something like this

```
 public user getLOGusr(String uname, String pass)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String select = "SELECT uid, username, email FROM " + TABLE_USRS + " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + " = ? AND " + KEY_PASS + " = ?";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(select, new String[]{uname, pass});

    user usr = new user();
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        usr.setUsrid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        usr.setuName(cursor.getString(1));
        usr.seteAddress(cursor.getString(2));

        PreferenceManager pm = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPrefs(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pm.edit();
        edit.putString("usrnm", cursor.getString(1));
        edit.commit();

        cursor.close();
    }
    else
    {
        usr = null;
    }

    return usr;
}
```

this is the function inside my dbhandler the problem is on the `.getDefaultSharedPrefs`part and the `.edit()` saying cannot resolve method the stuff im only trying to do is put the username into a session any help? thanks so much in advancve!

Comment: you need to see [Android Shared preferences example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example). Please Try searching things on SO before asking..!!

Answer (score 0):

Setting values in Preference:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
edit.putString("usrnm", cursor.getString(1));
edit.commit();
```

Retrieve data from preference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("usrnm", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
}
```

[Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Comment: what does the `MY_PERFS_NAME` mean?

Comment: Make a static variable like public static String MY_PREFS_NAME= "your_name". Give whatever name you want. This is for identify the preference.

Answer (score 0):

getDefaultSharedPreference takes Context object as parameter. By passing this you are passing reference to your dbhandler and not context.